# How to position objects relative to their parent

Tags: c#, windows, class

I am wondering if it is possible to position a panel relative to it's parent.
For example, I have a panel that every so often will receive a child panel, but instead of doing:
`newChildPanel.Location = Point.Add(parentPanel.Location,desiredLocation);`

I want to say:

```
newChildPanel.Location = Size.new(0,64);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this winforms, wpf, web...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the location by defining a new point: `newChildPanel.Location = new Point(0, 64)`. It will be relative to the parent's position.

For example:

```
Panel parent = new Panel();
parent.BackColor = Color.Red;
parent.Location = new Point(20, 25);
Controls.Add(parent);

Panel child = new Panel();
child.Parent = parent;
child.BackColor = Color.Blue;
child.Location = new Point(5, 5);
```

gives the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the child panel (blue) was added at (5, 5) relative to the parent's (red) position.

Answer (score 0):

newChildPanel.Location = new Point(0, 64);